Anyone familiar with Rabbi Meir Yechiel Holshtok's commentary on Avraham escorting the angels for 18 minutes?
I heard an amazing Dvar Torah that had incorporated what was stated by Rabbi Meir Yechiel Halshtok, and how he discovered that Avraham escorting the angels for 18min, was a mitzva with good intent, and thus received 2x reward. The hakarat hatov was brought by Hashem for 40 years in the desert, and Rabbi Meir Yechiel Halshtok discovered how the 18 minutes correspond to the 20 years of Hashem's time, doubling the reward to 40 years. I was wondering if anyone knows anything about this, where I can find his commentary on it, and also how it was inferred the 18min (מיל) was showing in the pesukim.
I just realized the Mil is coming from Kitzur Ba'al HaTurim on Genesis 18:16:1. He demonstrates that the words עַל־פְּנֵ֣י סְדֹ֑ם (מיל), the distance is derived from. Interestingly though he is deriving it differently, by saying that's the distance the angel escorted Lot if I understood correctly. But, now I know where the possible 18 min, comes from of Avraham Escorting, but I still can't find how the 18 minutes can correlate to the 20 years mathematically.

Welcome to the site. מיל means mile (by Chazal, usually the Roman mile), not minute.

So I believe the Mil they are referencing is from Shulchan Aruch. Some of the daily zmanim are described in terms of a mil. This refers to the amount of time it takes for the average person to walk a mil - 2000 amos. There are three opinions in the poskim as to how long that takes.
Some consider a mil to be 18 minutes, some 22.5 minutes, and some 24 minutes.[43]
Shulchan Aruch writes that it takes 18 minutes to walk a mil.[44]
Biur Halacha writes that some give an amount of 22.5 minutes.[45]
There are others quoted by Biur Halacha who maintain that the amount is 24 minutes.[46][47]

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
